# Yii2 пагинация и связь hasMany

Tags: yii2, pagination, relation

Есть выборка вида

```
$category = Category::find()
            ->where( 'slug = :slug', [ ':slug' => $slug ] )
            ->with('items')
            ->one();
```

Как правильно организовать разбивку по страницам в данном случае без использования dataProvider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то должно быть как-то так:

```
$query = Category::find()
    ->where( 'slug = :slug', [ ':slug' => $slug ] )
    ->with('items');

$countQuery = clone $query;
$pages = new Pagination([
    'totalCount' => $countQuery->count(),
    'defaultPageSize' => 15,
]);

$categories = $query->offset($pages->offset)
   ->limit($pages->limit)
   ->all();
```

Ну и во view идет categories и pages, вообще как с Pagination руками работать в мануале на сайте вроде есть примеры.

update: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html

update2: для определенности переименовал итог в categories, т.е. во view предполагается foreach ($categories as $category) и внутри у каждого уже foreach($category->items as $item)

update3:
Вариант, когда категория одна и надо навестить пагинацию на ее предметы: в таком случае предлагаю дергать сами предметы с выборкой нужной категории через джоин:

```
$items = Item::find()->joinWith('category')->where('category.slug' => $slug)->all();
```

Дальше с пагинацией все тоже самое, что и в первом варианте, во view при этом будет сразу проход по $items as $item. Можно еще сразу ->with('category') указать в запросе, если потом нужно будет что-то дергать через $item->category->..., чтобы избежать ленивые подгрузки.

Comment: Так пробовал, не работает, пишет

 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

`foreach($category->items as $item)` 

здесь в смысле

Comment: А поменяйте в конце ->all() на ->one(), это я уже что-то на автомате вставил не глядя на изначальный код.

Comment: Собственно, а что мы тогда пагинируем то, если категория одна, ее предметы? Если категорий все же предполагается несколько и их надо пагинировать, то все было правильно, но foreach должно быть два, сначала по списку category, а внутри уже у каждого по списку items.

Comment: @kroder вариант с all() был правильный. one() возвращает только одну запись из БД.

Comment: @atom-22 ну мне то это очевидно, просто до попытки автора пройтись сразу по category я как-то не обратил внимания, что изначально в вопросе она у него действительно дергается одна, поэтому вопрос в целом стал немного не ясным...

Comment: У меня выборка из связанной таблицы(items). Соответственно и в цикле я вывожу не категории, а записи которые принадлежат категории. Собственно эти записи я и пытаюсь вывести постранично.

Comment: Мне кажется в таком случае нужно дергать обратную связь через джоин, т.е. Item::find()->joinWith('category')->where('category.slug'  => $slug) или что-то подобное.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Добавьте свой комментарий отдельным ответом, отмечу его принятым.

Comment: Добавил в первый ответ, раз уж там расписано про пагинацию, если никто не возражает.

Comment: Столкнулся с такой проблемой, LinkPager генерит ссылки вида /test%2Fpage/2 ЧПУ настроил, должно быть /test/page/2 Т.е. если вбить в адресной строке /test/page/2 - все ок, но LinkPager генерит непонятные символы, из-за этого не работают ссылки

Comment: Я с таким не бодался, но проблема скорее всего в конфиге чпу, где вписан энкодящийся слеш, гуглится например такое: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027961/linkpager-widget-in-yii-2-generating-double-because-of-route-rule Если не разберетсь, то тянет на новый вопрос с цитатами из конфига.

Comment: Спасибо, сталкивался с подобным, помню что в LinkPager задается, а каким параметром не помню :(

Comment: Попробуйте создать аналогичную ссылку руками через createUrl - если слэш будет так же экранироваться, то вопросы все же к конфигу чпу.